# matlab 2012a install on ubuntu 12.04 64 bit cant specify license file

Tags: installation, java, matlab

[EDIT] The bug/error was the person sitting in front of my computer.. me.. Go to a more relevant question..

During installation of matlab 2012a I need to specify my license file but even though I mark the ratio button saying **I have the file installation key for my license** I'm not able to type any text into the text field.

Since everything else is working I suspect that it is Java or the fact that my Ubuntu is 64 bit that causes the problem.. So it might not be directly matlab related.

```
java -version says:
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.1) (6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Anybody having any suggestions?

Comment: Contact MatLab support, they'd be able to tell you whether this is a bug or if there's any method to get around it.

Comment: I'm very sorry to have wasted your time.. is was a embarrassing mistake from my part. Everything worked fine so please forget this question

Comment: PEBKAC!  xD  I'd put an answer in your question saying "This was a mistake on my part" and then choose that as your answer later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok.. Just to get something out of this.. If you find yourself unable to input the key during matlab install then beware that the input field only allow numbers so trying to input text simply doesnt do anything. You might thing the installer is broken... but that is not the case...

Comment: I was trying to add the path to my license file rather than a key, no wonder it didn't work. Thanks for your answer.